# HTML5: Create a custom element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create custom element that has a function which can be called from Jscript, but I can't get it working and don't see what's wrong...
My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var XFooPrototype = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);
XFooPrototype.foo = function() {
   alert("foo");
}

document.registerElement('x-foo', {
   prototype: XFooPrototype
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var mytag = document.getElementById("my_tag");
   mytag.foo();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <x-foo id="my_tag"></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

I would excpted that foo() is called and "foo" alert appears, but instead foo() is not defined when I call it.
Can someone point me to what's wrong on this?

(I know I should use class / extend and customElements.define, but this need to run on older browsers too)

Thanks!

Comment: Use the V1 style of Web Components and Use the Polyfills. These work back to IE11 (as long as you use the `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` for any code transpiled to ES5. But it is best to only transpile for IE11.

Answer (score 0):

`document.registerElement` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) in favor of `customElements.define()`. `document.registerElement` is deprecated even before most of the browsers knew this.

Therefore your current code should not work in most cases. New way of creating a custom element is-

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo id="my_tag"></x-foo>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super()
      }
      foo() {
        alert("foo");
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define('x-foo', MyElement);

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)     {
      var mytag = document.getElementById("my_tag");
      mytag.foo();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Currently Chrome supports this. Others are coming.

Custom element that older browsers can support can be created using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/).